# tikz-cd versus xy

Tags: xy-pic, tikz-cd

In certain circumstances, I plan to request for users to make use of `tikz-cd` package instead of `xy` package (because the latter [performs category code changes of `@` `\AtBeginDocument`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303238/18401)).

But, because I never used neither of them, I'd like to know what is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the sets of their features.

Comment: My pointer went straight to the “close as too broad” button, I stopped it with some effort. `;-)`

Comment: Nice! ;) I don't want to discuss which one is the best, just to know if users who would be requested to not use `xy` won't  be deprived of crucial features.

Comment: I'd rather tell your users not to go the `subpreambles` road. `;-)`

Comment: That just shows it is not opinion-based. It doesn't show the question is not too broad. What is it possible to typeset with TeX? is not opinion-based either.

Comment: @egreg That's not the users (math articles authors) who will make use of `subpreambles` option from `standalone` package: that's the class which will gather all the articles in a single volume of the journal.

Comment: @cfr The sets of features of both `xy` and `tikz-cd`, and hence the symmetric difference of them, are much less broad than the TeX's set of features. The purpose of my question is to get feedback from experimented users of these packages, e.g. to warn me if there is a killing feature of `xy` which is missing in `tikz-cd`.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I'm not saying whether it is too broad or not. I'm simply saying that the point you made doesn't address the broadness question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of features, in the strict sense, I haven noticed nearly no difference after a decade of using xypic and two years with TikZ.  The big difference is in access to the features.  TikZ requires the user to learn rather more to get started.  Just compare the documentation for the two (I might not have made the transition if there was not such good help available here at TeX StackExchange).   And then TikZ gives the user far more flexible results and easier fine control over the result than xypic.  As far as I know that control could also be gotten by sufficiently sophisticated use of xypic, but would require programming skill that I do not have.  I have done a little with getting the graphic to compute some of its own coordinates. That is easier in TikZ, with some help from TeX StackExchange.

Here is a good example of what xypic could do somehow, but TikZ does simply by setting a parameter:  [Drawing a cube with TikZ-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234147/drawing-a-cube-with-tikz-cd?rq=1)

My work is all with mathematical formulas, commutative diagrams, and geometric illustrations.  I have no experience with, say, trees, or displaying statistical data.